# htaccess prevent direct page load

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to prevent direct access to all php files on my site except index.php using htaccess. I've got following code so far, however it still does not prevent form accessing php files directly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My Solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|.*\.css|.*\.js|.*\.png|.*\.gif|.*\.jpg)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Put your PHP files you don't intend to be directly accessed outside of the server's web root directory.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Where you are explicitly telling the rewrite module to NOT run the following rules if the requested resource is a file or directory

However, I agree it's best to move them out of the web root entirely.

Comment: But if I remove those lines, I won't be able to load files like "style.css", or any images.

Comment: Sure you will, you just need to change your matching logic to not rewrite all files, and simply files that end in the extension `.php`. This is a trivially easy task - I think you can figure that part out.